# Publicly available high frequency financial datasets

Tags: data-request

I am looking for publicly available high frequency financial data e.g stocks, forex, etc. It would be great if someone can provide relevant links.

TIA!

EDIT: To be more specific, are there any open resources where I can get hourly/ minute level or tick data?

Regards,
Lesnar

Comment: To be clear, there is no "official" stock price at a given moment during intraday, except perhaps at the start and end of the trading day. There is a bid-ask spread, which is what buyers are willing to pay, and seller are willing to accept. Any intraday stock quote will be some combination of bid/ask, usually a simple average. To get real-time bid-ask data, you'd have to have access to a broker portal, since brokers are mediating the transactions.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yes, now I get it that I need access to some broker portal.

Comment: Do you need current or historical data (please update the question)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just came across this yesterday: https://github.com/eliangcs/pystock-data powered by https://github.com/eliangcs/pystock-crawler

There's also this measure of the CBOE Volatility Index on the [Open Knowledge Labs](http://okfnlabs.org/) datasets repository: https://github.com/datasets/finance-vix

Comment: But are there any open resources where I can get hourly/ minute level or tick data?

Answer (score 4):

I work at Quandl and we have data covering historical trade-based minute bars showing OHLCV for various stocks, but the data is not free. We do have pricing for single users, though.The databases cover the S&P 500 Index, Dow Jones Transportation Average, Dow Jones Industrial Average, Dow Jones Utilities Average and Nasdaq 100 Index. You can see the databases here: https://www.quandl.com/vendors/as Click on "View Pricing" to see the single user pricing for each database. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Not open but available for free:

- [Dukascopy historical feed](https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/)
- [TrueFX historical data](http://www.truefx.com/?page=downloads)